# What's the best way to edit text that is 'skewed' on a box?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, mockup, skew

So I have received a .psd file of the client but there are a few layers in it but no layers where I can click into (.psb file? The same kind of clickthrough layers you get from downloading Tshirt, Clothing, etc mockups the layer where you place your design in).

There is an example image below, the client asked to change some of the text etc, What's the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: fyi, it's a free [mockup from mockups-design.com](https://mockups-design.com/free-box-mockups-80x130x80-mm/) — you can download a version with layers from there.

Comment: I would make the smart objects if I didn't have a Photoshop file to work from.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thanks but the image was sadly just one that I took from Google, the actual image from the client is something different

Comment: @AndrewH There are no smart objects in the ps file... Or atleast not anymore. I suppose they were first but they converted them

Comment: @ZanicL3 - the PSD mockups do have smart objects. I just downloaded them and checked. Make sure you are opening the .psd files, and not the jpeg examples contained in the zip.

Comment: All you need to do is edit the smart objects and [add your own text like this](https://imgur.com/22nSIAI)

Comment: @BillyKerr No what I meant is that the mockup that I used above is just an example, the one for the client is something totally different (for context its more like a 'shop stand'), its not a box like this one. This was just clearly 'the' example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use smart objects to easily edit skewed graphics.

1. Use the Rectangle Tool (U) and draw the side of the object. It helps when you know the actual dimensions when creating the rectangle so you have the right proportions.
2. Right-click on the rectangle and convert it to a smart object.
3. Use Distort Transform to move the anchor points to fit the object.
4. Double-click on the smart object layer to open it in a new window.
5. Put your graphic/text in the new smart object window and then save.

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you so much dude!